# I can't change android camera resolution

Tags: android, parameters, camera, resolution

This is my code in onPreviewFrame Method.

The frame that shows on the surfaceHolder is fine.

I Already set the resolution with this code at first

```
 mCameraParameter = mCamera.getParameters();
 mCameraParameter.setPreviewSize(100,150);
 mCameraParameter.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
 mCameraParameter.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
 mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParameter);
```

but the picture that image get is 640 * 480

I wonder why i can't change the preview resolution.

```
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.e("PreviewCallBack", "Preview");


        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Log.e("Picture Size", "width : " + parameters.getPreviewSize().width);
        Log.e("Picture Size", "height : " + parameters.getPreviewSize().height);
        Log.e("Array Size", "data.length : " + data.length);
        YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(),
                parameters.getPreviewSize().width,parameters.getPreviewSize().height, null);


        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + "/"+/*System.currentTimeMillis()*/"out.jpg");

        FileOutputStream filecon = null;

        try {
            filecon = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        image.compressToJpeg(
                new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 90,
                filecon);
    }
};
```

Comment: `setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG)` is useless. I have never seen an Android device that supported this. In your own example, you expect YUV format for the data received in `onPreviewFrame()` callback.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are trying to set an unsupported preview size. Better call "**getSupportedPreviewSizes()**" and check if the preview size you want to set is supported by your device before calling **setPreviewSize()**.

Comment: Also, `Camera.Parameters.setPreviewSize()`, or more exactly, `Camera.setParameters()` should not be called after `Camera.startPreview()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call [`setPictureSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize%28int,%20int%29) to set the size of the picture itself (not the preview).